# PHP shell_EXEC not executing cpp

Tags: php, shell

this question may be asked more times, but I can't find the solution,

when I run the following command in my linux shell 
     cd /home/pi; ./kaku 1 A on it runs, but when I use PHP to do the same with `echo shell_exec('cd /home/pi; ./kaku 1 A on');` it simply doesn't run my code.

Comment: ensure your working directory is the one `kaku` is in.

Comment: I tought that's why I am using cd/home/pi

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
shell_exec('/home/pi/kaku 1 A on');
```

Comment: Thanks for the ccomment, but still no response.

Comment: What does log tells after your script execution?
Could you do a 
tail  /var/log/apache2/error.log
(Assuming that you are using apache)

Comment: I am sorry , That gives me a message that I need to fill in the parameters. but when I try passing the parameters with shell_exec('/home/pi/kaku; 1 A ON');  no response is given

Comment: If your command kaku need a parameter, you don't need to put a semicolon inside shell_exec

Comment: echo shell_exec('/home/pi/kaku 1 A ON'); still gives the same issue

Comment: Ok. Could you tell us what kaku is doing?
Currently your are passing 3 parameter to kaku.
If you need to pass 1 A ON as 1 parameter you should write : 
shell_exec('/home/pi/kaku "1 A ON"');
you also should ensure that your command is executable through www:data.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but  shell_exec('/home/pi/kaku "1 A ON"') returns usage: /home/pi/kaku address device state
example: /home/pi/kaku M 10 on

Comment: Yes running it via the CLI gives no problems at all.

Comment: Ah yes I can see it need 3 parameter not 1. When you run your script is it through a web browser?

Comment: Yes it is running on apache.

Comment: Ok, does apache user (www-data) has execution right on your script?

Comment: I used chmod to modify the permisions to 777 , is that what you mean?

Comment: with 777 you will be sure that every user can execute the script, however it is not recommended, but for testing if you put chmod 777 and you still have no result, it means that your problem is not related to right access

Comment: So the way of passing the parameters should be diffrent?

Comment: From what I see it should be shell_exec('/home/pi/kaku 1 A on');
Without wrapping parameter by double quote, but if it doesnt work and your access right is 777, I don't knwo what is wrong from now